# Issue with windows shell right click extension in folder background

Tags: windows, menu, registry, contextmenu, windows-shell

It is very simple to add a custom command to the shell context menu like so:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\TestCommand]
@="My Test Command"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\TestCommand\command]
@="notepad.exe"
```

This adds a custom command to the right-click menu that launches notepad. Since I added it in Directory\Background\, my understanding is that the command should only show up when I right-click in the background of a directory (for example, right clicking an empty area in the right pane of Windows Explorer).

My issue is that the command is also showing up when I right click on an item in the left pane of Explorer (i.e. right clicking on a drive or folder in the treeview). Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I am launching a custom application with arguments and the result is unpredictable if the user is able to launch it from the left pane.

Answer (score 0):

Add;

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\TestCommand]
@="My Test Command"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
```